# Time and distance: Police and a thief with a twist.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, puzzle

A thief was given a head-start of 15 hour. The velocity of the thief being 4 km/hr and the police chasing after him be 5 Km/hr. A dog is moving to and fro between the police and the thief, starting from 
 the police at a velocity of 10 Km/hr. Every time the dog touches the thief it gives him a bite which reduces the speed of the thief by 10%.

1. When will the police catch the thief?
2. What would be the distance covered by the dog by that time?
3. What would be the distance covered by the dog in the forward direction?

Answer Not given.

How can I get the answer without writing a program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a $(t,y)$ coordinate system, let $$(t_n,p_n)\qquad (n\geq0)$$
with $(t_0,p_0)=(0,0)$ be the "world points" where the dog meets the police, and let
$$(h_n,s_n)\qquad(n\geq1)$$
be the "world points" where the dog hits the thief. Then
$$p_n=5t_n\qquad (n\geq0)\ .\tag{1}$$
When the thief is  hit for the first time we have
$$60+4h_1=s_1=10 h_1\ ,$$
which leads to $(h_1,s_1)=(10,100)$. The sequel is governed by the following recursion formulas:
$$\eqalign{s_n-p_n&=10(t_n-h_n)\cr s_{n+1}-p_n&=10(h_{n+1}-t_n)\cr
s_{n+1}-s_n&=4\cdot 0.9^n(h_{n+1}-h_n)\ .\cr}\qquad(n\geq1)\tag{2}$$
Use $(1)$ in order to eliminate $p_n$ from $(2)$; then eliminate $t_n$.
And on, and on$\ldots$